# Information box appearing on hover in chrome, any suggestions on if you can disable this?

Tags: google-chrome

I've been using chrome for a while, and about a month ago i noticed when hovering over a box that can be typed in (E.G the youtube search bar, this text box i'm filling in to make this post, the title box on the same page.)

I get a grey box popping up where my cursor is pointing. now the strange thing is it doesnt happen everywhere. E.G the search box at the very top of the page doesn't trigger it.

I'm just not sure why its happening, and if there's any way to disable it, it disappears when I click or start typing, just it's been bugging me since it started happening.

the info I'm getting when I hover over this box

[image: Screenshot of said issue]

I know its not a huge issue, but it's bugged me enough that I thought I'd at least ask and see if anyone had any suggestions.

I've had a look in the flags page on chrome, but i've not found anything that stands out as something that has caused the issue.

The issue persists through a fresh install, and it persists when using incognito.

I have tried signing out of sync just in case that's causing the issue, along with deleting all of my extensions, and i've tried disabling javascript for the pages im having the popup on all with no dice

My apologies if this isn't the correct forum for a post like this, this is my first post, and hopefully with it being a software question posting my question here is allowed.

EDITS: Added screenshot of the error persisting in incognito mode:

[image: Incognito screenshot]

Comment: If this is caused by some extension, see if this happens in Incognito mode where extensions are disabled.

Comment: Harrymc. i have already tried that bud, no dice, still getting the same popup. i've tried doing a uninstall and reinstall, deleting all my extensions, and in incognito and it still persists.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this thread on a forum](https://community.webcore.co/t/fixed-chrome-webcore-overall-type-unknown-type-server-type-no-server-data-dialogue-error/7783/12), this behavior is enabled using a Chrome flag:

```
chrome://flags/#show-autofill-type-predictions
```

This flag needs to be either “default” or “disabled”.

Comment: Thank you. that seems to have fixed it. no idea how that setting got changed as earlier this week was the first time i had a look in the flags section. appreciate the help.

Comment: @OnyxBlackScale Don’t forget to “accept” this answer if it solved the problem.

Comment: not seeing any way to accept, i've not used this site before, if you could point me in the right direction that would be great.